# Stop UITextField cursor from blinking in iOS

Tags: ios, cursor, uitextfield

Is there a way to stop the cursor from blinking in a UITextField? I know you can use `[UITextField resignFirstResponder]` and `[UITextField setEnabled:NO]`, but I'd like to keep the keyboard visible on the screen.

Thanks!

**Update**

To clarify, I have no intention of hiding the cursor while the user is editing the text field, but I want to hide it after the user has hit Done and a progress indicator has appeared above the text field. A blinking cursor seems weird in a view that can't be manipulated with.

Comment: It seems unlikely. Blinking cursors are pretty standard (and for good reason). Also be careful, Apple might not approve an app that circumvented this.

Comment: It's likely that @PengOne's right about the approval part. I've posted a hack of sorts to get it one as part of my answer [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367354/how-to-show-a-uidatepicker-over-the-tab-bar-in-an-orientation-friendly-way/6367432#6367432). There have to be some modifications though as to implementing the delegate methods and synchronizing the label text with the text field's one.

Comment: If you're hiding the cursor because you don't want the user editing the text in the field, why keep the keyboard there either?

Comment: @BoltClock: the relevant `inputView` may not be a keyboard, so a cursor doesn't always make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an invisible text field and make it the first responder. Once you're done, you can set the first responder back to the original text field and remove the invisible text field.

Comment: Could you provide any source code? I don't get it - when should I make original textfield first responder? It always showing blinking cursor after that for me. Is there way to delete that cursor? Thanks for any answer.