# How to stop cursor blink in UITextField iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, xib

I am altering an old project, which uses XIBs.

When project is running on a device, when I touch the text field to edit, the cursor is blinks one time.

I need to stop that blinking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop UITextField cursor from blinking in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374595/stop-uitextfield-cursor-from-blinking-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this theoretically. But can do a trick.

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:yourTextField.backgroundColor];
```

if your **UITextField** background color is not set (or default color) then you need to set

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```